# Making Html Tags Visible on Website To Make It Look Good

Tags: html, css

How to make my website look from:
[image: Original Look Of Website]

To This Look:

[image: What I want To achieve]

I'm using CSS, JavaScript And Html, But I don't Know how to achieve that type of look to My website

Comment: Please create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+style+html+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: this is an X/Y problem. Just make a background image

Comment: Pls can you share your source code.

Comment: https://anonfiles.com/1ac1beE5yb/Portfolio_rar @HYDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add line (`div`) and use `::before` and `::after` on it.

```css
body {
    margin: 40px;
    background-color:#0f0e0e;
    font-family:Arial;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.flex > div:last-child {
   margin:10px 0 10px 15px;
}
.flex h1 {
   color:#d7d6d6;
   font-weight:100;
   margin:0;
}
.flex p {
  margin:0;
  color:#a6a3a5;
  font-size:0.9rem;
  font-weight:100;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.line {
    width: 1.5px;
    background: #333030;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.line::before {
    content: "<h3>";
    position: absolute;
    color:#483f3f;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(-43%, -100%);
}

.line::after {
    content: "</h3>";
    color:#483f3f;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translate(-45%, 100%);
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="flex">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div>
         <h1>Simpfey</h1>
         <p>An Indie Web Dev.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does not look much like the picture.

Comment: @mplungjan now it looks.

Answer (score 0):

CSS and images

```css
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #0F0E0E;
}

.side {
  width: 125px;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 125px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6aic.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content {
  font-family: "Bahnschrift light", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 5em;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="side"> </div>
  <div class="content">Simpfey</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ...but there's no `<h3>` elements in your HTML.

Comment: Why would there need to be?

Comment: ...otherwise it's dishonest and/or incorrect: it's a `<div>` advertising itself as though it's a `<h3>` when it isn't.

Comment: This is a visual effect to show the dude does HTML. What is dishonest about it?

Comment: ...because a `<div>` isn't a `<h3>`.

Comment: As I said, he wants a visual representation of some HTML, it is MUCH harder to make an H3 BE an H3 AND show the HTML at the same time. You would have to NEST the H3 and that is invalid so my solution makes more sense than an actual H3

Comment: @Dai Why don't you complain in the other answer. There is also no h3, just a string in a pseudo content